# How to query nested unamed jsonb objects and order?

Tags: postgresql, query, jsonb

have an audits column (jsonb) seems like:

```
{{"status": "pending", "updated_at": "2022-06-20T15:58:54-03:00"},{"status": "active", "updated_at": "2022-06-27T21:30:41-03:00"}}
```

want to order by **updated_at** in the object that has status = **"active"**.

```
{"status": "active", "updated_at": "2022-06-27T21:30:41-03:00"}
```

Comment: Please provide a valid JSON sample. The current one is not valid. I suppose it should really be a JSON array? And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your values are really JSON ***arrays***, [`jsonb_path_query_first()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) with this [path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) would do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY jsonb_path_query_first(audits, '$[*] ? (@.status == "active").updated_at')::timestamp
```

Also assuming the key `updated_at` contains valid `timestamp` literals.